# Using hasNextInt with do-while loop, no error message for negative integer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am writing a program that includes a test for whether the user input is a positive integer and displays an error messagge if the entry is a non-integer or negative. My code displays the intended error message if a non-integer is entered, but only re-prompts to enter a positive integer if a negative integer is entered. I've tried adding:

```
if (n <= 0);
System.out.print("You have not entered a positive integer");
```

before

```
 n = input.nextInt();
```

but that makes an error message appear even if a positive integer is entered.

I have also tried:

```
while (!input.hasNextInt() && n <= 0)
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int n = 0;

        do {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        while (!input.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.print("You have not entered a positive integer. \nPlease enter a positive integer: ");
            input.next();
        }
        n = input.nextInt();

        } while (n <= 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int n = -1;//<-- it won't allow user to skip the loop after first pass without proper input
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
    try {
        n = input.nextInt();//<-- in one pass ask input from user only once
        if(0 > n) {
            System.out.print("You have not entered a positive integer. \nPlease enter a positive integer: ");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number !");
        break;//<-- break loop here, if don't wana prompt user for next input
    } catch(java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Oops number is required !");
        break;//<-- break loop here, if don't wana prompt user for next input
    }
} while (n <= 0);
```

Comment: Exception is too big a exception to be used here, just use NumberFormatException.

Comment: I tried this and got an infinite loop when a non-integer was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int n = -1;
while (input.hasNextInt() && (n = input.nextInt()) < 0)
{
    // print error message about negative number
}
```

When the loop exits, if 'n' is still -1 you got to the end of the input, e.g. the user typed ctrl/d or ctrl/z depending on the platform.

If the user is at the console you might also need to skip to end of line.

Comment: I tried this and the program didn't run when a positive integer was entered.

Comment: "Didn't run" meaning what exactly? It will break out of the loop above as soon as a positive number is entered.

Comment: It prompted to enter a positive integer, but when a positive integer was entered, it did not break out of the loop and print results.